# Ordering by json field in ruby Sequel/Postgres

Tags: json, ruby, postgresql, sequel

I'm using the Sequel library in Ruby by Jeremy Evans and I'm trying to order by a field in json.

I can get this to work in SQL with this Postgres query:

`SELECT * FROM files ORDER BY json->>'filename' ASC`

but i can't get this to work with Sequel/Postgres

`table.order("json ->'filename'")`

This results in the following SQL:

`SELECT * FROM "files" ORDER BY 'json ->''filename'''`

giving the error:

`PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  non-integer constant in ORDER BY
LINE 1: ... ORDER BY 'json ->''...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved:

`table.order(Sequel.lit("json ->'filename'"))`